# Stream video on VLC Player Android over SFTP with SSH key authorization

Tags: ssh, ftp, vlc

I would like to connect via SFTP with public/private key encryption with VLC on Android (both on my Chromecast TV and Android phone).

I have installed Termux, configured my keys, and can access the SSH server via Termux. How would I supply my ssh keys to VLC?